# How to extract x.509 certificate and display its fields in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services, x509, pki

Need to decrypt fields in x.509 certificate with file extension .cer in angular2 application. https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkijs is a library. However, not very sure to use in angular2. Can anyone please help? Thank you!!

Comment: Is just the decryption your problem? Did you try anything yourself? Add code, if possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you check this example? https://pkijs.org/examples/X509_cert_complex_example.html

Answer (score 1):

Just above the section 'Examples', https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkijs says:

"So, here is step-by-step description on how PKIjs parses binary PKI structures:

1. Binary data parsed via ASN1js package (asn1js.fromBER function). Outcome from this step is ASN1js internal classes;
2. In order to produce a "helper" user need to provide data from step #1 to specific class of PKIjs to function .fromSchema (for example Certificate.fromSchema). Usually code will looks like const cert = new Certificate({ schema: asn1.result }) - this code internally would call Certificate.fromSchema function;
3. Inside fromSchema function PKIjs class would parse ASN1js internal structures and produce easy to access class properties. Also in fromSchema PKIjs compare input ASN.1 structure with how it should like (compare with pre-defined ASN.1 schema);

So, usually user would use this code snippet:

```
// Parse a X.509 certificate
const asn1 = asn1js.fromBER(binaryData);
if(asn1.offset === (-1))
    alert("Can not parse binary data");

const certificate = new Certificate({ schema: asn1.result });`
```

Here is step-by-step description on how PKIjs class data converts back to binary representation:

1. User need to convert PKIjs class to ASN1js internal class. In order to do this user need to call .toSchema function;
2. As a result from step #1 we would have ASN1js structures. And each of ASN1js structure has its class member toBER - this function would return binary representation of ASN1js structure as ArrayBuffer;

So, usually user would use this code snippet:

```
const certificateBinary = certificate.toSchema().toBER(false);
```

From `certificate`, you should be able to extract all the data you are interested to display. Did you use this solution? If not, which did you find?